# Avoid typing MySQL connection data in form action PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, database, security, mysqli

Today I wrote my first PHP script to input data to the database by user click and filled in textareas using POST method.
But I am sure this is not secure - the form action is referring to a PHP document, which inserts the data in DB. In this document are shown the MySQLi connection properties, such as servername, database name, password and username.
I am using 000webhost for building my websites.
So now I don't understand how can I avoid putting into PHP file the MSQLi connection properties, actually, how to avoid the access of third parties to this connection data at all?
The PHP needs DB connection attributes, on the other hand, everyone may open the source code of that PHP file and see the details of connection and I don't want them to do this.
Could you please help me out with this?

Code below:

```
 <?php
$servername = "here is the server name";
$username = "I type here the username";
$password = "Here comes the password";
$database = "And the DB name";

// Create connection
$connection = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

// Check connection
if (!$connection) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

echo "Connected successfully"; //I just check the connection here, so it's for me just
// Establishing Connection with Server
$db = mysqli_select_db($connection,"DATABASE name here"); // Selecting Database from Server
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ // Fetching variables of the form which travels in URL
$name = $_POST['name'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$address = $_POST['comtext'];
if($name !=''||$email !=''){
//Insert Query of SQL
$query = mysqli_query($connection,"insert into comments(comments_name, comments_subject, comments_commenttext) values ('$name', '$subject', '$address')");
echo "<br/><br/><span>Data Inserted successfully...!!</span>";
}
else{
echo "<p>Insertion Failed <br/> Some Fields are Blank....!!</p>";
}
}
mysqli_close($connection); // Closing Connection with Server
?>
```

Comment: If you site is setup correctly, you cannot download a `.php` file, you can only execute it.

Comment: _on the other hand, everyone may open the source code of that PHP file_ Who are these people you refere to here?

Comment: The PHP code runs on the server, not the browser, so everything in the PHP tags is replaced before being sent back to the user. Try looking at the page source of the rendered page to see it for yourself.

Comment: If the PHP code itself is displayed when you visit the page, then you have a problem with the way that your webserver is setup.

Comment: Btw, all of the echo statements will go back to the browser, so "Connected successfully" and "Connection failed" are not really just for you.

Comment: While your current concern is groundless, there is a real vulnerability in your code that opens your database for anyone. Please use  prepared statements for your database interactions: [How to run an INSERT query using Mysqli](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli_examples/insert)